# What time do shops close in Taipei?

Tags: shopping, taiwan, opening-hours

My question is pretty straightforward but somehow broad... I would like to narrow it down to:

- Shops in Malls
- "Normal" shops (e.g. the one in [Camera Street](http://www.tripadvisor.com/Attraction_Review-g293913-d1776249-Reviews-Camera_Street-Taipei.html))
- Vendors in street (small markets and so on)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally shopping malls in Taipei open by 11 AM but other shops open by 10am.

It says here: http://www.asiatravel.com/taiwan/taiinfo1.html

> Working hours department and other stores are 10:00-9:30 pm (some stores
>   upto 22h)

This page says http://www.worldtravelguide.net/taipei/shopping

> Shops are open daily 1000-2200, while night markets stay open till
>   0100 and convenience shops are open 24 hours.

As for shopping markets, including [camera market](http://camstreet.com.tw) (boai road), you can see here:

http://aaround.com/taipei-shopping/

http://www.taipeitrends.com.tw/camera-market/

Comment: I don't suppose you have any specific info about camera street, do you?

Comment: Updated the answer.